# Support for VIEW as well as TABLE in ndbunit

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, ndbunit

Due to the design of the SQL database I am using, operations have to occur on the views and not the tables (in essence, there are triggers to stop insert/update/delete on the tables). For this reason I am using ndbunit against the views.

This works fine for ReadXmlSchema and GetDataSetFromDb, but

```
PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.DeleteAll);
```

fails with the error:

> Cannot alter 'MySchema.vw_someView_myView_Maint' because it is
>   not a table.

My searches found this can be overriden in the JAVA [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#views) by overriding the [tableType](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html#tabletype) property. Is this functionality available in nDbunit ?